# How to create default custom value of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I want to customize the default value of my dropdownlist, Like having a value of **"Select an item"** instead of the value exist from the Database.

**View**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Vendor)
```

**Model**

```
 [UIHint("SellerDropDown")]
    public MDL.Vendor Vendor{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Vendor, mySelectList, "Select an item");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesn't work, because I'm using 
'@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Vendor, Model.Vendor,"Select an Item");
I can't use Html helper **DropDownListFor** because I using Custom helper to bound to database.